# The R code for computing the Cohen's f2 effect size (for multilevel models)

Tags: r

Until now, I have not found the R syntax for computing the f² Cohen's effect size. There's this [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3328081/) from Selya et al. (2012) that talks about it and that gives the SAS code. There's also the Stata code [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/xtmixed_effect_size.htm). If I dare to ask, can anyone here transpose the SAS or Stata code into R code ? I will REALLY appreciate the help if my wish is granted.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `pwr` package on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/index.html).

You have the `cohen.ES()` function:

```
library(pwr)
cohen.ES(test = 'f2', size = 'large')
```

Or different effect size calculators based on if you're working with proportions, chi-square tests, t tests, ANOVAs, etc.

As an example:

```
pwr.anova.test(k = 4, n = 20, sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8)
```

returns:

```
Balanced one-way analysis of variance power calculation 

          k = 4
          n = 20
          f = 0.3788014
  sig.level = 0.05
      power = 0.8

NOTE: n is number in each group
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess my question lacks clarity. The two articles I have cited referred to how to calculate Cohen's f2 for multilevel regression models. I have modified the title of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon the same question and didn't find an available function to compute f2 for multiple regression. However, I found the formula on the [Quick-R Power Analysis page](https://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html) and wrote my own code to compute it:

```
# If we are evaluating the impact of a set of predictors on an outcome, then the f2 formula is:
R2 = # input your R2
f2 = R2/(1 - R2)

# Else, if we are evaluating the impact of one set of predictors above and beyond a second set of predictors (or covariates), then the f2 formula is:
R2AB = # input your R2AB
R2A = # input your R2A
f2 = (R2AB - R2A)/(1 - R2AB)
```

If you have multilevel data, however, you might need to adapt this formula.